Small children wander through dream (without speech)
About 12 - 15 years ago I watched an anime that seemed old even then so I assume the show to be from the beginning '90 (but I'm uncertain).
It did not contain any "language" to speak of, instead all verbalizations where blooping sounds that kind of transported the tone of what was said (angry, sad, bored...) and the gesture etc. had the meaning, but no words were used.
As far as I remember the story began with two siblings were one lost his personality and the other (older iirc) sibling set out on an adventure to retrieve it. The older has to watch over the younger as it has lost all will (it didn't swim when dropped in water etc.)
The movie was in very simple figures, flat coloring, shadows etc. only where they were necessary.
Everything was very(!) dream-like. Figures morphed into landscapes and visa versa, there was no "continuity" between the scenes, etc.
The only scene I remember in some detail goes like this:
The siblings approach a circus and are invited with the gestures and pathos of such a scene to attend the show. They take their seats and the show begins. The show ends as the elephant handler starts to ligate parts of the elephant which then pop like a waterballon. But as he ligated the stomach the elephant grew ever larger and exploded, flooding everything. The older sibling then catches something that can be used as a boat, pulls the younger one on board and starts rowing.
The whole movie was disturbing and irritating and I forgot how it ended.

"disturbing and irritating" Makes you wonder why you're after it, then... ;) But other than that, a very detailed question. Posted a possible match.

@Walt There are days where I want to be irritated and disturbed, so thats not something "bad" :) And you got it right, thank you.

Sounds like you're after the short film Cat Soup (AKA Nekojiru-so) from 2001. From Wiki:

The surreal [film] follows Nyatta, an anthropomorphic kitten, on his travel to the land of the dead and back in an effort to save his sister's soul.

There's no dialogue and it includes this scene:

During their outing they visit the 'Big Whale Circus', the final act of which is a giant penguin-looking bird "filled" with various weather, causes a flood of water which covers everything. The two of them end up on an Ark-esque boat with a pig...

The film is available on Youtube:



